# How to login into a website and fetch some data from it and give it to another website

Tags: php, web-services, web

I have a website 'A' and a website 'B' both requires users authorization.

Assuming that i have the users authorization can i login using website 'C' into 'A' and fetch data from it?

Is it necessary that website 'A' should have some API to do it ?

I want the data to be fetched from website 'A' and transferred into website 'B' via website 'C' 
Is it possible ?

Comment: Why is this tagged `php` and `asp.net`. Which one are you using?

Comment: sorry i am a newbie.I would use PHP

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. May you please share some code so we could better understand your issue?

Comment: that cant be 100% safe, but you could try to make a restful API and pass a token along that